# Object return null on language change odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have English and French language installed in my odoo 8. I am getting a weird situation. I am getting value from stock picking type table as below.

```
type='Internal Move'
Picking = http.request.env['stock.picking.type'].search([('name','=',str(type))])
```

Here I am getting the object value as stock.picking.type(4,).

But if I change my language to French , I get no value (stock.picking.type())

Comment: Interesting, can you debug and find out if 'lang' is set correctly in 'env.context'?

Comment: Hi CZoellner, this is the env context variable: {'lang': u'fr_CA', 'tz': u'Africa/Abidjan', 'uid': 1} for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with *code* field. *code* is a selection field which holds value *incoming,outgoing and internal*

In your case, we can use *code as internal*

Try with following:

```
Picking = http.request.env['stock.picking.type'].search([('code','=','internal')])
```

NOTE:

If you have multiple *internal* type of operation, then it will return you more then 1 ids. So take care of your another requirement.

Comment: Thanks Odedra, But why i am not getting value if it exists in Database ? thats also only if you change language. Moreover, can i get all the value for internal and then check for name as 'Internal Move'